# Kendo grid sending date in wrong format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

it is kendoui grid working against webapi  (.net mvc 4 project)
the kendoGrid part in my js file:

```js
$("#eventsgrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: { url: "/Webapi/V2/.../events", type: "GET" },
                update: { url: "/Webapi/V2/.../events", type: "PUT" },
                create: { url: "/Webapi/V2/.../events", type: "POST" },
                destroy: { url: "/Webapi/V2/.../events", type: "DELETE" }
            },
            pageSize: 10,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "eventId",
                    fields: {
                        eventId: { type: "number", editable: false, nullable: true },
                        eventCode: { type: "string" },
                        eventLocation: { type: "string" },
                        clientId:{ type: "string" },
                        startDate:{ type: "date" },
                        endDate: { type: "date" }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        columns: [
            { field: 'eventId', title: 'ID', width: '50px', filterable: true },
            { field: 'eventCode', title: 'Code', width: '80px', filterable: true },
            { field: 'eventLocation', title: 'Location', width: '150px', filterable: true },
            { field: 'clientId', title: 'Client', width: '80px', filterable: true },
            { field: 'startDate', title: 'Start', width: '80px', format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", filterable: { ui: "datepicker" } },
            { field: 'endDate', title: 'End', width: '80px', format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", filterable: { ui: "datepicker" } },
            { command: [{ id: "edit", name: "edit", text: "Edit" }, { id: "destroy", name: "destroy", text: "Delete", width: "30px" }, { text: 'Details', click: gotouser }], title: "&nbsp", width: "240px" }
        ],
        sortable: true,
        editable: "popup",
        filterable: {
            extra: false,
            operators: {
                string: {
                    startswith: "Starts with",
                    eq: "Is equal to",
                    neq: "Is not equal to"
                }
            }
        },
        toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add new Event" }],
        pageable: { pageSizes: true | [10, 20, 30] }

    });
```

the problem is: when i edit a record, or post a new one, the value i receive in my mvc controller for any of the date fields, is null.
when i check in my chrome tools, see what the grid sends to the controller (when you hit update in the popup), like this:

```js
    clientId: 1
    startDate: Tue Jan 20 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
    endDate: Thu Jan 22 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
    logo: abcsd.jpg
    featured: 4
```

obviously the date format is wrong, and i suppose that is why the controller does not see it as a date, the conversion/binding fails, and it gives me null.

How do i make it send a different format, like mm/dd/yyyy ? isn't that covered by the format definitions in the columns array?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use parameterMap function. Look at [kendo parameterMap documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-transport.parameterMap).

Similar to this:

```
parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
    if (operation != "read") {
        var parsedDate = kendo.parseDate(data.startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy");;
        data.startDate = parsedDate;
        return data;
    }
}
```

For kendo parsing dates look at [kendo parseDate](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateparsing#date-parsing)

Comment: Thank you! What is the return object? options is not defined. maybe should be 'operations'? or data?

Comment: Thank you! What is the return object? options is not defined. maybe should be 'operations'? actually data makes sense. I traced this code, and in the line var d= new Date...  it fails to convert the date. any idea?

Comment: try kendo.parseDate(data.startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy");

Comment: No, still "invalid date". now, the input date is like "Tue Jan 20 2015...." so i can manually parse this date, but it looks ugly, and I can't believe that kendo will require me to do that, when my use is straight forward, nothing fancy. Anways, thanks a lot for trying, i will send this to telerik.

Comment: ok, i got it. i followed your line, and now it's working. for other people:

Answer (score 1):

in the parameterMap use:

```
var parsedDate = kendo.toString(data.startDate, "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

the kendo.parseDate function takes a string as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

OK, I followed Dmitriy's line, and was able to make it work. so for future generations, here is what you need to add to your js:

```js
update: {
                    url: "/Webapi/..../events",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "PUT",
                    data: function (data) {
                        data.startDate = kendo.toString(data.startDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
                        data.endDate = kendo.toString(data.endDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
                        // repeat for all your date fields
                        return data;
                    }
                },
// same thing for your 'create'. 
// Sorry, look like a bit of 'Repeat yourself', but at least it's working.
```

So again, big thanks to Dimitriy!